# Jenkins: Copy to a dynamic target location using the current branch in the file operations plugin

Tags: file, variables, jenkins, operations

What is the correct formatting used to access the BRANCH_NAME variable in the file operations plugin-> file copy? The target location to be exact.

I have tried %BRANCH_NAME%, ${env.BRANCH_NAME} but jenkins keeps taking them literally and creating the directory with the same name, i.e. c:\%BRANCH_NAME%

Jenkins Version 2.72

File Operations Plugin Version 1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my installation with Jenkins 2.60.2 and File Operations Plugin 1.6, `${BRANCH_NAME}` works for me.

Comment: Does BRANCH_NAME show up in your job's environment variables? How was the job created to generate BRANCH_NAME for future reference?

Comment: @scranley For my test, I just injected an environment variable in called BRANCH_NAME (since that's what yours was called).  I believe (but I'm not certain, so don't quote me on this) that when doing things like a multi-branch pipeline, the branch name is stored in the BRANCH_NAME environment variable.  I'm going to assume (based on your experience) that this is not the way it's done in other project types, but yeah, GIT_BRANCH is the variable exposed by the Git plugin for the branch name.

Answer (score 0):

BRANCH_NAME didn't exist under the build# environment variables, but GIT_BRANCH did. ${GIT_BRANCH} used as the target folder created a folder with the branch name.